# Volley и JSONRequest

Tags: android, json

Всем привет, начинаю разбираться с библиотекой Volley и вообще работой с JSON,
создал приложение которое получает данные с JSON и отображает их в Recyclerview, но проблема заключается в следующем - сервер отдает только первые 20 записей, а остальные записи на других страницах

```
"_meta": {
"totalCount": 21,
"pageCount": 2,
"currentPage": 1,
"perPage": 20
}
```

Как возможно перейти на другую страницу и получить данные и оттуда ?

Comment: Это надо спрашивать у вашего сервера.  Раз он отдаёт записи постранично,  значит у него должна быть возможность получить записи с "конкретной страницы" .  Когда докрутили список до конца,  запрашивайте очередную "страницу"

Comment: скорее всего добавить в запрос параметр вроде &page=2 или &offset=20 или &start=21. Это должен сказать вам разработчик серверного API, т.к. только он знает, как он это сделал

Comment: Да и вообще, вопрос не имеет отношения ни к JSON,  ни к Android

Comment: Окей, я просто не совсем точно выразился, мне с приложения нужно перейти на другую страницу и получить данные с нее. Хотя в принципе я просто переделал серверную часть и теперь мне отдает все записи. Спасибо

Comment: И вопрос таки имеет отношение и к JSON и к Android.